# VBA Internet Explorer Webpage Link Selection

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, hyperlink

My current code opens a website and logins. the next step is that I want to select a link on the next page but don't know how to get the code to click on it (first time messing with HTML code). below is a picture of the HTML behind that link. If more info is needed I can update with more pictures.

[image]

```
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<div class="gwt-Hyperlink">PRC search by selection</div>
</td>
```

My Excel code:

```
Sub Login()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
   ' ie.navigate "http://sqa.subaru-sia.com/nxps/nxps?action=defaultPage"   ' Modify the URL here....
Const Url$ = "http://sqa.subaru-sia.com/nxps/nxps?action=defaultPage"
 Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
 
    UserName = "xxxxxxx"
    Password = "xxxxxxx"
    
    With ie

    .navigate Url
    ieBusy ie
    .Visible = True

    Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
    Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("j_username")(0)
    Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("j_password")(0)

    oLogin.Value = UserName
    oPassword.Value = Password
    .document.forms(0).submit

    End With

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
 
   Set myColl = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each myItm In myColl
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = "Table# " & ti + 1
        ti = ti + 1: i = i + 1
        For Each trtr In myItm.Rows
            For Each tdtd In trtr.Cells
                'Debug.Print (tdtd.innerText)
                If tdtd.innerText = "PRC search by selection" Then
                    tdtd.Children(0).Click
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Next tdtd
            i = i + 1: j = 0
            DoEvents
        Next trtr
        i = i + 1
    Next myItm
    
    'ie.Quit
End Sub


Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description, it looks like you want to click the link with the text **PRC search by selection** on the page using IE VBA Automation.

If we try to check the HTML code in the image then we can notice that the page contains nested tables and what you are assuming as a link is actually a `DIV` tag. So I am assuming that you want to click the `DIV`.

I tried to make a test webpage with the nested tables and a similar kind of DIV and try to click the DIV using the code below.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim ie
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://Your_website_here..."   ' Modify the URL here....

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
 
   Set myColl = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    For Each myItm In myColl
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = "Table# " & ti + 1
        ti = ti + 1: i = i + 1
        For Each trtr In myItm.Rows
            For Each tdtd In trtr.Cells
                'Debug.Print (tdtd.innerText)
                If tdtd.innerText = "PRC search by selection" Then
                    tdtd.Children(0).Click
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Next tdtd
            i = i + 1: j = 0
            DoEvents
        Next trtr
        i = i + 1
    Next myItm
    
    'ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your own requirements.

Comment: I get Run-Time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method. on `For each trtr In myItm.Rows`    I will update my question with the full length of code. The first part of the code gets me past the login screen onto the screen with the div that I need to select.

Comment: I am not sure why you had tried to get the `DIV` instead of `Table` in this line `Set myColl = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")`. You need to get all Table elements. Further, try to check whether `ie.document` is properly assigned after moving to the next page. If not, you can again try to assign it.

Comment: When I run the code the Immediate window says "Loading. Please wait..." I think this is cause the code is running faster than IE can keep up. Also even when it finds the tdtd.innertext that I want to be select it doesn't select it.

Comment: If you think the code execution is faster than IE then try to wait for some seconds using `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)`. I suggest you debug the VBA code step by step by pressing the `F8 key`. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes the code was going to fast and passing over the elements as the page loaded, I added the wait and it fixed the issue.

Comment: From your last comment, it looks like your issue is solved now. If the suggestion is helpful, I suggest you accept it as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future with similar kinds of questions. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I forgot to click the check mark last time I was on here.